# TypeORM: "No migrations pending" when attempting to run migrations

Tags: node.js, nest, nestjs-typeorm

Steps to reproduce or a small repository showing the problem:

I am working on a project with typeorm on nestjs. the problem is even after running migration after generating migration files, i get No migrations are pending

The commands i am using are

```
"scripts": {
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./dist/modules/config/app-migration.js",
    "migration:create": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:create ./src/migrations/migration",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert",
    "migration:generate": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./src/modules/config/app-migration.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/migration"
  },
```

Packages version :-

```
"typeorm": "^0.3.11",
"typeorm-cli": "^1.0.7"
"ts-node": "^10.0.0",
"tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
```

BTW: my src/module/config/app-migration.ts file looks like this

```
import { cwd } from 'process';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import configuration from './configuration';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();

const {
  database: { username, password, database, host, port, schema },
  nodeEnv,
} = configuration();

let entities = '/src/**/*.entity.ts';
let migrations = '/src/migrations/*.ts';
if (nodeEnv.toLowerCase() === 'production') {
  entities = '/dist/**/*.entity.js';
  migrations = '/dist/migrations/*.js';
}
const dataSourceObj: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: host,
  port: parseInt(port),
  username: username,
  password: password,
  database: database,
  schema: schema,
  entities: [cwd() + entities],
  migrations: [cwd() + migrations],
  extra: {
    seeds: [cwd() + '/src/seeds/*.ts'],
  },
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
  synchronize: false,
  dropSchema: false,
};
export const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceObj);
export default dataSourceObj;
```

I tried
npm run buld
npm run migration:run

Out Put

> base-nest-project@0.0.1 migration:run
> npm run typeorm -- migration:run

> base-nest-project@0.0.1 typeorm
> ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./dist/modules/config/app-migration.js

query: SELECT * FROM current_schema()
query: SELECT version();
query: SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema" = 'rms-academic' AND "table_name" = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM "schema"."migrations" "migrations" ORDER BY "id" DESC
No migrations are pending

Answer (score 0):

in typeorm version 0.3.x
you have to provide the entities, migrations,.. with array,
the use of glob pattern is deprecated

so try with something like this it will work :

```
const ENTITIES=[User]
const MIGRATIONS=[migration1]

export const DATA_SOURCE_OPTIONS: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost',
  port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10),
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  entities: ENTITIES,
  migrations: MIGRATIONS,
  migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations',
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
  migrationsRun: false,
  synchronize: false,
};

export default new DataSource(DATA_SOURCE_OPTIONS);
```